# How to add Values to list<valuepair> object 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the `List<ValuePair>` object: `listUserRoleValuePair`. I have to add `ixUser` and `name` as my value pair in the list in foreach loop. How I can Add this?

```
List<ValuePair> listUserRoleValuePair = new List<ValuePair>();
var ixUserList= _mapper1.FindUserRoleLike(sName);
User result = null;

foreach (var ixUser in ixUserList)
{
    result = new UserMapper(connection).FindById(ixUser);
    var name = result.SFirstName + " " + result.SLastName;

    //listUserRoleValuePair.Add(ixUser);
    // listUserRoleValuePair.Add(    
}
```

my ValuePair class is as below

```
public class ValuePair
{
    private string _index;
    private string _sName;

    public ValuePair(string index, string sName)
    {
        _index = index;
        _sName = sName;
    }

    public string Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set { _index = value; }
    }

    public string SName
    {
        get { return _sName; }
        set { _sName = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the ValuePair class

Comment: @SteveDog he may mean `KeyValuePair`. Is this correct Manoj?

Comment: Its not KeyValuePair . its ValuePair but similar to KeyValuePair I think ..

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you have a custom `ValuePair` class when it looks like it provides the same functionality as the build in `KeyValuePair` dictionary class?

Comment: Answer 1 ,2 and 3 Worked Fine without any Modification ..

Comment: We use the ValuePair in many parts of the code...If any changes are there especially datatype , those changes are directly done in the Valuepair class ..

Comment: ValuePair sounds to be either like `Tuple<T1, T2>` or `KeyValuePair`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided ixUser is the index string, use this code:

```
List<ValuePair> listUserRoleValuePair = new List<ValuePair>();
var ixUserList= _mapper1.FindUserRoleLike(sName);
User result = null;

foreach (var ixUser in ixUserList)
{
    result = new UserMapper(connection).FindById(ixUser);
    var name = result.SFirstName + " " + result.SLastName;
    listUserRoleValuePair.Add(new ValuePair(ixUser, name));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the KeyValuePair class:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> listUserRoleValuePair = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
```

And then:

```
listUserRoleValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(name, ixUser);
```

You can also use a Dictionary instead of a List.

Comment: He said `ValuePair` not `KeyValuePair` :)

Comment: +1. The OP does not reveal any datails on the type `ValuePair`. Therfore it is fair to assume that its functionality is comparable to `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`. Maybe the downvoter can explain why he downvoted?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It wasn't me, but Manoj added the details of the ValuePair class after this answer was posted.

Comment: @mattytommo: Yes the OP said `ValuePair`, but it is fair to suggest using an existing type instead of creating a new one, and with a little mental flexibility one can infer easily what the answer for `ValuePair` would be.

Answer (score 2):

```
listUserRoleValuePair.Add(new ValuePair(index, name));
```

Im, not clear what the index value is for your objects, but whatever it is, just replace it in the line above

Answer (score 2):

you can add only items that support the child object type in your case you can use one of these.

```
collection.Add(new ValuePair(index, Name))

or
collection.Add(new ValuePair(){Index = index,SName= Name});
```

or very simple create object and pass as

```
Valuepair valpair = new ValuePair();
valpair.Index = index;
valpair.SName = name;

collection.Add(valpair);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var pair = new ValuePair();
// somehow intialize pair
listUserRoleValuePair.Add(pair);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listUserRoleValuePair.Add(new ValuePair(ixUser, name));
```